# How can I make Amazon Lex V2 to initiate the conversation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Looking for a way to set up a bot in Amazon Lex that can start conversations with users (not waiting for user input) through Twilio-WhatsApp channel!

any ideas?